# How to save CheckBox Checked Item If I scroll

Tags: java, android

I have created a RecycleView contains check boxes
when I check Item and scrolls the check item gonna be unchecked it does not save the action I gonna explain in the pic
this is before scrolling when checked the first item[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhisZ.png)
after scrolling
it changed to default as unChecked[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZdfl.png)

and here's My adapter Class

```
package abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.R;
import abtech.waiteriano.com.waitrer.getters_and_setters.ItemsListsModel;

/**
 * Created by yassin on 5/17/17.
 */

public class RecycleAdapterDialogModifier extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapterDialogModifier.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<ItemsListsModel> modifierArrayList;
    ArrayList<Boolean> positionArray;


    public RecycleAdapterDialogModifier(Context context, ArrayList<ItemsListsModel> modifierArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.modifierArrayList = modifierArrayList;
        positionArray = new ArrayList<Boolean>(modifierArrayList.size());
        for(int i =0;i<modifierArrayList.size();i++){
            positionArray.add(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.modifierlistitem, parent, false);


        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ItemsListsModel itemsListsModel = modifierArrayList.get(position);
        holder.modifierCB.setText(itemsListsModel.getName());

        holder.modifierCB.setFocusable(false);
        holder.modifierCB.setChecked(positionArray.get(position));
        holder.modifierCB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked ){
                    System.out.println(position+"--- :)");
                    positionArray.set(position, true);

                }else
                    positionArray.set(position, false);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modifierArrayList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CheckBox modifierCB;
        TextView usernameContItem;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            modifierCB = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemCb);

        }
    }
}
```

sorry for my bad english and If there's any thing is not clear

this is the part in Class Calls Adapter

```
private static void setPiking(String modeCode) {
    RecyclerView modifierItemList;
    Button OkBtn, CancelBtn;
    LayoutInflater inflater2 = (LayoutInflater)  context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view2 = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.modifier_list, null);
    modifierItemList = (RecyclerView) view2.findViewById(R.id.modifierList);
    OkBtn = (Button) view2.findViewById(R.id.okBtn90);
    CancelBtn = (Button) view2.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn90);
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.myDialog));

    ModGroubeCode = Integer.parseInt(modeCode);
    String Sql = "SELECT  dbo.Items.Code, dbo.Items.Name FROM dbo.Items";
    ResultSet RS = ConnectionClass.Ret_RS(Sql);
    try {

            ArrayList<ItemsListsModel> modifierArrayList = new ArrayList<ItemsListsModel>();
            while (RS.next()) {

                builder1.setMessage("Modifier Group :- " + RS.getString("ModifierGroup_Name"));
                String name = RS.getString("Name");
                String id = RS.getString("Code");
                TreeMap<String, Object> arr = new TreeMap<String, Object>();



                ItemsListsModel itemsListsModel = new ItemsListsModel(id, name, arr);
                modifierArrayList.add(itemsListsModel);
            }
            adapter = new RecycleAdapterDialogModifier(context, modifierArrayList);
            modifierItemList.setAdapter(adapter);

        builder1.setView(view2);
        builder1.setCancelable(true);

        final AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();

        OkBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        CancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alert11.dismiss();
            }
        });


        alert11.show();


        if (Mo_multiPick) {
            //show Ok
            OkBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            OkBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if (Mo_allawNoPick) {
            //show Cancel
            CancelBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            CancelBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the activity code that uses the adapter?

Comment: @Hahn have a check I posted the part of the class calls adapter

Comment: Are you calling the setPiking method at regular intervals?

Comment: @Hahn yeah It's a method in externl Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing `itemHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);` just before `holder.modifierCB.setChecked(positionArray.get(position));` to ensure that `OnCheckedChangeListener()` is not triggered.